# How to rearrange col-12 order in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I have the following columns:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">A</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">B</div>
```

So, on "sm" they go:

```
[A][B]
```

and on "xs" they go:

```
[A]
[B]
```

I want, on "xs" to swap their order to:

```
[B]
[A]
```

But, adding `.pull` and `.push` doesn't work (they simply go out of screen):

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-push-12 col-sm-6">A</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-pull-12 col-sm-6">B</div>
```

Comment: `push`, `pull` are the preferred way, you just need to think mobile-first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use floating classes also `pull-left` or `pull-right`

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 pull-right">B</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 pull-left">A</div>
```

This way [B] will come on right and [A] will come on left in big screen like this because of pull classes

```
[A][B]
```

and in small screen when they come 100% they will come like this

```
[B]
[A]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to design for mobile first, then desktop. So the initial arrange should be the smaller screen, and then pull or push for bigger devices

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-6 col-xs-push-6">B</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-6 col-xs-pull-6">A</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

Use V-4 Bootstrap from http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/utilities/

```
<div class="pull-xs-left">Float left on all viewport sizes</div>
<div class="pull-xs-right">Float right on all viewport sizes</div>
<div class="pull-xs-none">Don't float on all viewport sizes</div>

 <div class="pull-sm-left">Float left on viewports sized SM (small) or wider</div>
<div class="pull-md-left">Float left on viewports sized MD (medium) or wider</div>
<div class="pull-lg-left">Float left on viewports sized LG (large) or wider</div>
<div class="pull-xl-left">Float left on viewports sized XL (extra-large) or wider</div>
```

That way you can make div float on xs or sm.

**Solution 2:**

Make a CSS fix using media query

```
@media(max-width:767px)
{
 .a
  {
   float:right;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard Bootstrap approach to this is to use the column ordering classes and think "mobile-first". First create your mobile layout, and then adjust it  for `sm` screens using the `push`, `pull` classes.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-push-6 col-sm-6">B</div>
    <div class="col-sm-pull-6 col-sm-6">A</div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/UST50mXjZW

Also the `col-xs-12` classes aren't necessary since this is the default behavior.